# Issue in Yolov4 training with backup weights

Tags: google-colaboratory, yolo

I am trying to train yolov4 using already saved weights in colab. But the training process stops abruptly after loading the weights. Below is the log, after **Create 6 permanent cpu-threads**, execution stops:

```
[yolo] params: iou loss: ciou (4), iou_norm: 0.07, cls_norm: 1.00, scale_x_y: 1.05
  nms_kind: greedynms (1), beta = 0.600000 
  Total BFLOPS 59.563 
  avg_outputs = 489778 
  Allocate additional workspace_size = 52.43 MB 
  Loading weights from 
 /content/drive/MyDrive/YOLOv4_weight/backup/yolov4_custom_train_final.weights...
 seen 64, trained: 192 K-images (3 Kilo-batches_64) 
Done! Loaded 162 layers from weights-file 
Learning Rate: 0.01, Momentum: 0.949, Decay: 0.0005
Detection layer: 139 - type = 27 
Detection layer: 150 - type = 27 
Detection layer: 161 - type = 27 
Saving weights to backup/yolov4_custom_train_final.weights
Create 6 permanent cpu-threads
```

The weights I am trying to use were generated after 3000 epochs and yolov4.conv.137 was used as the initial weights data; as the accuracy was low I want to run it for 5000 epochs with the saved weights.

Comment: There could be two possibilities are outlined here (https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/issues/752). Firstly, you could try increasing your max_batches. Also, make sure to check if train.txt and test.txt are not empty. The script could stop after `creating cpu threats` when there is nothing in those files.